# Channels Websocket immedialty disconnecting with ssl

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, django-channels, daphne

I tried to make run the tutorial from the channels [docs](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/index.html) on my production server, using ssl.
After a few hours i managed to get a connection but it instantly disconnects :

```
None - - [12/Mar/2018:17:42:22] "WSCONNECTING /ws/chat/bibou/" - -
None - - [12/Mar/2018:17:42:22] "WSCONNECT /ws/chat/bibou/" - -
None - - [12/Mar/2018:17:42:23] "WSDISCONNECT /ws/chat/bibou/" - -
```

my stack is

```
ubuntu 16.04
nginx 1.10.3
channels==2.0.2
daphne==2.1.0
channels-redis==2.1.0
Twisted==17.9.0
```

I have the exact copy paste of the code from the tutorial, except for this part in room.html

```
var chatSocket = new WebSocket(
    'wss://' + window.location.host +
    ':8443/ws/chat/' + roomName + '/');
```

and here is my nginx conf

```
server {
    #http
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    #https
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 8443 ssl;
    server_name domain.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem";
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location /static/ {
    root /home/ubuntu;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/ubuntu;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/tlebrize/Project.sock;
    }

    location /ws/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/tlebrize/Daphne.sock;
    }
}
```

I run daphne with `daphne -u Daphne.sock Project.asgi:application -v 3`

I also tried bypassing nginx and using `sudo daphne -e ssl:8443:privateKey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.co/privkey.pem:certKey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.co/fullchain.pem Project.settings:CHANNEL_LAYERS`
but i had the same results.

The front break with the message Chat socket closed unexpectedly with the error code `1011 (Internal Error)` and no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work, it was an issue with nginx and/or using ReconnectingWebSocket. here's my whole working conf:
nginx

```
server {
#http
listen 80;
server_name domain.co;
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

location / {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
}

server {
#https
listen 443 ssl;
server_name domain.com;
root /usr/share/nginx/html;

ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem";
ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem";
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

location /static/ {
root /home/ubuntu;
}

location /media/ {
    root /home/ubuntu;
}

location /ws/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8443;
}

location / {...}
}
```

daphne
`sudo /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/daphne -e ssl:8443:privateKey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem:certKey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem Project.asgi:application -v 3`

js

```
var chatSocket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(
    'wss://' + window.location.host +
    ':8443/ws/chat/' + roomName + '/');
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I've forgot to include `CHANNEL_LAYERS` to `settings.py`.

Server was even able to send 1-2 messages before disconnecting.

This was resulting in error 1011 when connecting through `nginx` and 1006 when connecting directly without https/wss. I tried both uvicorn and daphne.